# Sorting data in a sheet with added information Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

My work has a Google Form where different information is inputted. All this information is then automatically put into a Google Sheet. We will call it "All data sheet".
"All data sheet" has multiple sheets in it, one with all of the data and then one for each type of data which needs to be given to different people. One of those is called 'Caretaker'.

I then have a second Google Sheet (example called 'Sorting') that pulls everything from the 'Caretaker' sheet onto 'Import_range'.

This allows the caretaker to see everything that needs fixing with the oldest thing at the top and the newest at the bottom.

The caretaker would like the newest at the top.
I can easily make another sheet (see 'Sorted') that uses the sort function to put the newest at the top.

However, he would also like another column where he can either check a box to show it's done or write an x.

When new data appears, the checked box does not move down.

Is there any way to sort the data but also have an input column which stays with the sorted data?

[Link to example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zy6SckMCSATnB9GMwbbBafFMMoeYti6HV6b3GwUJHT4/edit#gid=286411014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Google Apps Script.

### Try this:

1. To start, go to **Tools** and click **Script editor**.
2. Delete the code in **Code.gs**
3. Paste the code provided below and save
4. Refresh your Spreadsheet and **Custom Menu** will pop up in the Menu
5. Go To **Custom Menu** and Click **Update Sorted Sheet**

*First execution will require user's authorization. Once you authorized the script, make sure to rerun the Custom Menu.*

The code below will create a **Custom Menu** in your Spreadsheet. Clicking the custom menu will execute a function that will update the Sorted Sheet and retain its checkbox values.

I also added comments to explain the function of each line in the code.

**Code:**

```
function updateSorted() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Import_range");
  var sortedSh = ss.getSheetByName("Sorted");

  /* Use this if the Import_range is from different spreadsheet
  var iSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Insert Sheet ID here");
  var sh = iSS.getSheetByName("Insert Sheet name here");
  and comment the var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Import_range"); above*/
  
  /*
  Check if the Sorted Sheet has data. 
  If true, compare Sorted Sheet and Import_range data
  else, copy Import_range data to Sorted Sheet. 
  */
  if(sortedSh.getLastRow() > 1){ 
    
    var sData = sortedSh.getRange(2, 1, sortedSh.getLastRow()-1, 5).getValues(); //remove unnecessary data
    var sDataFiltered = sData.filter(e => e[4]); //get Date column of Sorted sheet
    var sDates = sortedSh.getRange(2, 5, sortedSh.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues().flat(); 
    var sDatesFiltered = sDates.filter((a) => a); //remove unnecessary data
    
    
    var importDates = sh.getRange(2, 4, sh.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues().flat(); //get Date column of Import_range
    
    //convert dates to String format
    var arr1 = sDatesFiltered.map( dateString => String(dateString))
    var arr2 = importDates.map( dateString => String(dateString))
  
    var difference = arr2.filter(x => !arr1.includes(x)); //get the difference between arr1 and arr2
    difference.forEach(dates => {
      
      var index = arr2.indexOf(dates); //get new entry position in Import_range
      var newEntry = sh.getRange(index+2, 1, 1, 4).getValues().flat(); //get row data of new entry from Import_range
      newEntry.unshift(false); //append false in the beggining of the array
      sDataFiltered.push(newEntry); //append new entry to sDataFiltered array
    })

    var range = sortedSh.getRange(2, 1, sDataFiltered.length, 5);
    range.setValues(sDataFiltered); //set the values of Sorted sheet using the sDataFiltered array as data
    sortedSh.getRange(2, 1, sDataFiltered.length, 1).insertCheckboxes(); //get the checkbox range and insert checkbox
    range.sort({column: 5, ascending: false}); //sort the data by Date column

  }else{
    var range = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow()-1, 4);
    var data = range.getValues();
    data.forEach(row => {
      row.unshift(false)
    })
    var sortedRange = sortedSh.getRange(2, 1, data.length, 5);
    sortedRange.setValues(data);
    sortedSh.getRange(2, 1, data.length, 1).insertCheckboxes();
    sortedRange.sort({column: 5, ascending: false});
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Update Sorted Sheet', 'updateSorted')
      .addToUi();
}
```

### Examples:

**Populating Empty Sorted Sheet:**

[image]

**Updating Import_range sheet, clicking checkboxes and updating Sorted Sheet:**

[image]

### Implementing Time Driven Triggers:

1. Open your Apps Script project.
2. At the left, click Triggers alarm.
3. At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
4. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create.
5. Click Save.

For time driven, your trigger setup should somehow look like this:

[image]

The example trigger above will update the sheet every minute. The down side of using time driven trigger is the quota limit. Gmail accounts are limited to 90 minutes of total runtime. Exceeding quotas will result to errors. See [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas).

---

### Using Buttons: Alternative to Custom Menu

To create a user friendly button in your Sheet

1. Go to **Insert** -> **Drawing**
2. Draw the desired button shape and style.
3. Click **Save and Close**
4. Move the button to your desired position
5. Right click, click the 3 vertical dots and select **Assign script**
6. Type **updateSorted** and click **OK**
7. Click the button to run

*Note: If you decided to use buttons and want to remove the Custom Menu in your sheet, just remove the **onOpen** function in your Apps Script.*

### References:

- [Google Apps Script on Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#legacy-editor)
- [Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. Is there a way to make it update automatically or do I need to click the "Update Sorted Sheet" button? The person getting this stated he is not a computer person and I might be hard pressed to convince him he needs to push the button to resort.

Comment: @tierratheseeress - To make it automatic, you can use Time Driven Installable Trigger. This will update the sheet on a given time. I added an example above that will update the sheet every minute. The down side of using Time Driven Trigger is gmail accounts are limited to 90 minutes of total runtime per day. You have to adjust the interval to avoid errors. Which leads me on using buttons or custom menu. I also added Buttons example in my answer above. This is more user friendly than the  custom menu.